# How to create a type that can be pass through in a stored procedure in out param?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, types

The type is declared in an stored procedure.

```
 TYPE colletreal_t IS RECORD( 
      TeminatNo         NUMBER(10), 
      TeminatTutar      NUMBER(26, 2), 
      IpotekTutar       NUMBER(26, 2), 
      TeminatKalanTutar NUMBER(26, 2), 
      IpotekKalanTutar  NUMBER(26, 2), 
      MunferitTur       NUMBER(30), 
      TeminatTur        NUMBER(10), 
      IpotekMarjOran    NUMBER(12, 6), 
      TeminatTip        VARCHAR2(1),                  
      KarsiladigiRisk   NUMBER(26, 2)); 
   TYPE colletrealtable_t IS TABLE OF colletreal_t INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

How can I make these types colletrealtable_t so that I can use as it in out parameter of a procedure to transfer complex array to another layer in db.

Comment: You can either define these types in a package or at the schema level define `colletreal_t` type as object and `colletrealtable_t ` as nested table.

Comment: take a look at the [`create type` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375)

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `object` and then create a `type` of the object and then use the collection as `out` parameter to the procedure. How to create an `object` I leave it to you. Below is an exmaple of how you can create a type. I created a type of varchar. You can create a type of your `object`. Here in the example am passing a colletion to procedure and populating the other collection. You can use the passed parameter as a out and get it used anywhere else.

```
create  type var_a is table of varchar2(30000) ;           


 create or replace procedure collcetion_as_in_out_parmtr (
   a_var   in     var_a,
   b_var      out var_a)
as
begin
   --Assigning the input collection to out collection
   b_var := a_var;
end;
```

Execution & Output:

```
SQL> set serverout on;
SQL> declare
  2     var var_a;
  3    begin
  4  
  5      collcetion_as_in_out_parmtr(var_a('A','B','C','D','E'),var);
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Elements of collection'); 
  7      for i in var.first..var.last 
  8      loop
  9       --displaying elements of collection
 10       dbms_output.put_line(var(i));
 11     end loop;
 12  
 13    end;
 14  /    

 Elements of collection
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```